# How to use xpath extractor for rest api response in jmeter?

Tags: rest, xpath, jmeter

I'm using Jmeter for Rest API testing,in that i required errorMessage Parameter value but i'm using xpath extractor as

```
//errorMessage
```

In place of xpath query

Response is :

```
{
   "cardNo": "87878787",
   "name": "John Doe",
   "offerIds": ["cq"],
   "allowedDiscValue": 0,
   "amount": 1000,
   "otp": -1,
   "dob": "01-01-90",
   "errorMessage": "SUCCESS",
   "mobileNo": null
}
```

I require only errorMessage

Answer (score 3):

Just use JSON Extractor with expression:

```
$.errorMessage
```